# Implementing a protocol method inside of a subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Consider the following code inside of a Module that is included via Cocoapods (I'm using `Eureka`, but the problem should not be related to that):

```
open class FormViewController : UIViewController {  
}

extension FormViewController : UITableViewDelegate {    
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // some default implementation
  }

  /// some other UITableViewDelegate methods follow, but _NOT_ willDisplayCell
}
```

I am trying to subclass `FormViewController` and add an implementation for `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` (which is an optional method from `UITableViewDelegate`). This method has no implementation in the origin `FormViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import Eureka

class MyViewController: FormViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .grouped)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView = tableView
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView!)

        super.viewDidLoad()

        form = Form()
        let section = Section()
        section.append(EmailRow(){
            $0.tag = "email"
            $0.title = "Email"
        })
        form += [section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("NOT CALLED")
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("will be called")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("GETS CALLED")
        return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    }
}

/// somewhere else:
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MyViewController(), animated: true)
```

With this setup, my overriden version of `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` will be called (meaning that `tableView.delegate` is set up properly). `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` will not be called. As soon as I add a blank implementation in Eureka, I'm able to override the method.

Question: Why is Swift not using the method without a default implementation in the superclass?

Comment: Can you add in description how do you declare instance you your ViewController in the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've noticed this problem myself, and it seems like a bug to me. You have two options.

First, you can implement the delegate method inside your extension and override it in your subclass. this will ensure the method is called.

```
extension FormViewController : UITableViewDelegate {    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // you can leave the implementation blank if you want
    }
}

class MyViewController: FormViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("CALLED!!")
    }
}
```

Second, you can declare the method using the pre-Swift 3 notation and it will work. This part also feels like a bug to me (or all part of the same bug). I wouldn't recommend this option as it is likely to change in future Swift or Xcode versions and generally feels hacky.

```
extension FormViewController : UITableViewDelegate {    
    // no willDisplayCell method
}

class MyViewController: FormViewController {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("CALLED!!")
    }
}
```

EDIT: The fact that OP put the `UITableViewDelegate` methods in an extension isn't causing the problem. The problem exists even if the class itself decalres the delegate.

Comment: I've tried the first approach - it seems to only work if the extensions is located in the same module than the original implementation. Nevertheless, this is the best solution for now.

Comment: Got the solution? Me too facing same issue in swift 5.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding extensions defined on a superclass don't work on the level of a child class if this is what you mean. You can implement a method however that you call from the child class to the super class to perform some default kind of behaviour specified in the class' extension.

Comment: In addition to my answer, stated by the apple docs : Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.

Comment: This problem will still occur if the `UITableViewDelegate` methods are declared in the class itself instead of an extension.

Comment: Well I think that can probably only happen when super.viewDidLoad() is not called from the child class since he is setting the delegate and the datasource in the viewDidLoad() method. If the delegate and datasource are properly assigned and the delegate and datasource methods are overriden in a child class everything should work as expected.

Comment: Well if the superclass declares it conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` but doesn't implement `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)`, then the child can't override that method. The child just declares that it can handle that particular method. And that situation is where the method isn't called like it should be.

Comment: @keithbunter you are right indeed about overriding. But can't the child class just implement the missing method without overriding any thing from its super class?

Comment: If the child implements the method without overriding, then the method isn't called. That is the basis of this whole question.

Answer (score -1):

May be the problem is in controller instance declaration.

```
let myController: MyFormViewController = MyFormViewController()
tableView.delegate = myController
```

In this case everything should work correctly. But in another case

```
let myController: FormViewController = MyFormViewController()
tableView.delegate = myController
```

`tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)` will not been executed.

Comment: I doubt this is the problem